# How do independent vendor BIOSs manage to integrate it OEM hardware?

Tags: x86, hardware, bios

Microsoft DOS didn't need drivers because DOS is written to depend on a BIOS ABI which handles talking to hardware for it. This [site](http://www.linux-tutorial.info/modules.php?name=MContent&pageid=107) states:

> "The standard BIOS for PCs is the IBM BIOS, but that's simply because "PC" is an IBM standard. However, "standard" does not mean "most common," as there are several other BIOS vendors, such as Phoenix and AMI."

How can an OEM (say the people who put my ASUS laptop together) just take one of these "Phoenix or AMI" BIOSs off the self, stick it in, and have it work?

I would have thought the OEMs would have to write there own specific BIOSes to access the specific hardware they put together. Either that, or all the OEMs are going to have to put things together in a way that the "Phoenix and AMI" etc off the shelf BIOSs can access.

How do these BIOSs that are developed by independent manufacturers manage to integrate with OEM hardware?

Answer (score 1):

Companies may pay an IBV to do the work for them, or they may pay for the right to use the IBV's core BIOS and make additions/changes themselves.

Comment: Links? Also what is an IBV?

Comment: Independent BIOS Vendor.